# Comparing withCount from nested relation belongToMany Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, count

I have 3 tables: Brands, Branches, Items.
The relationship is

> Brand hasMany Branches
>
> Items belongToMany Branches
>
> Brand HasMany Items
>
> Item hasOne Brand

An item can be at multiple branches and the other way around.
Since there will be new branch data. I need to keep checking the branch_item pivot table.

So I need to display items if there are any missing items on new branches.

Items model

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function branches()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Branch', 'branch_item', 'item_id', 'branch_id');
    }
}
```

My query so far

```
$itemsq = Item::with('brand.branches_count')->withCount('branches');
$itemsq->having('branches_count', '<=', DB::raw('brand.branches_count'));
$items = $itemsq->paginate(10);
```

The error

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'branches' in
>   'having clause'

I cant use

```
withCount('brand.branches_count')
```

I need to display a list of items only if there are missing pivot data on them related to Branch's total table. 
Example: If there are 10 total branches, and pivot table branch_item only contains 6 data.
Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, my question is does Brand and Item have relationship? My understanding is from Brand to Branch got relationship and Branch to Item got many to many relationship, as mentioned by you, but why your query put brand as the first relationship for item model?

Comment: yes I forgot to add them, Brand HasMany Items, I edited the question

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, is this what you want?
Item::doesntHave('branches')->get();
Might sound silly because I don't really understand the thing you try to achieve...